# How do I ignore a route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a route i.e. mysite.com:3000/new_route that I'd like to ignore, is this possible to do through rails and not server side?

I've read that this can be done through apache, however, my app is running on Heroku and that type of control isn't accessible to me. Therefore, I'm looking for another way to do this through Rails.

Thanks

**update**

I am using faye to have live notifications in my app, on `localhost` `faye` runs on `port 9292` - `localhost:9292/faye`, all good in development mode, but in production it should point to `mydomain.com/faye`, there are no port numbers in production environment, and loading `faye.js` returns `error not found`

Comment: What do you mean by _ignore_? Do you want it routed somewhere else? Should it return a 404? What?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when I access  mydomain.com/blog it should not be processed by blog controller or any other resource in my app, /blog is a link to an external app.

Comment: Better say, I am using faye to have live notifications in my app, no localhost faye runs on port 9292 - `localhost:9292/faye`, all good in development mode, but in production is should point to `mydomain.com/faye`, there is no ports numbers in production environment, and loading faye.js returns error `not found`,

Comment: Please update your question with that information.

Comment: updated, original post

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a resources route you don't want to be created:

```
resources :something, except: :new
```

However, I'm not exactly sure if this is what you meant by ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a route at the top of your `routes.rb` file that will redirect to some other page.

```
get '/new_route', redirect: '/'
```

Comment: this is NOT  a good option, can not fix the problem and it brings into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you ask Rails to process the route, it is already too late. If you ask rails to process a route, it will, either by returning a 404 of 500 error, or a page.

If you want the route to be processed by another application, it will need to be intercepted by your webserver (`nginx` or `apache`, or whichever one you're using). In their configuration, you just redirect that route to the other application, and every other route to the Rails app.

**EDIT**

Another option you have, is to forward your requests to a different server.

You add a route like

```
get 'faye/*query' => 'faye#get'
post 'faye/*params' => 'faye#post'
```

And then a controller

```
require 'faraday'

class FayeController < ApplicationController

  APP = 'http://mydomain.com:9292'

  def get
    request_page :get
  end

  def post
    request_page :post
  end

  private 

  def request_page(method)
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => APP)
    query = params.delete(:query)
    response = conn.send method, query, params
    render text: response.body.gsub(APP, 'mydomain.com/faye')
  end
end
```

which will use Faraday to load the information from your other application.

Comment: thank you, any idea on how to configure this on heroku?

Comment: I added another option, more suitable for Heroku